# Likelihood that a group of NFL teams have a certain number of All Pros at any given position?

Tags: p-value

Over the past 20 years, 12 Super Bowl winning teams (60%) have had at least one player from its defensive front 7 selected to be All Pros. Three of those 12 teams has had two players selected to be All Pro. Two of those 12 teams had three players selected to the Pro Bowl. What is the likelihood that this is random?

**Background**

Each NFL team has 7 starting players on it's front 7. (The front 7 includes 3 or 4 defensive linemen; and the other 4 or 3 playing linebacker).
18 players are chosen each year to be All Pro out of all the 224 starters across all 32 teams in the NFL.

Comment: To put it a little differently, any randomly chosen team out of a league of 30 teams is expected to have 18/30 = 0.6 All Pro defensive linemen, so that over 20 years such randomly-chosen teams ought to have had around 20 * 0.6 = 12 All Pros.  Your data indicate the Super Bowl winners had 13 All Pros--almost identical to the expected value.  Need we do any further analysis?

Comment: When looked at that way, 18/(32*7), or 8%, of front seven players in the league are All Pros. 19/(7*20), or 14.5%, of Super Bowl winning players were All Pros.

Comment: Could you explain where the value of 19 comes from?  From 11 teams with one player and one team with two players I get only 13.  I also compute that 19/(7*20) is 13.6%, not 14.5%.

Comment: @whuber: Sorry, my bad. I edited the original post.